# re-sizing a fits image in python

Tags: python, image-resizing, fits, astropy

I have 5 astronomy images in python, each for a different wavelength, therefore they are of different angular resolutions and grid sizes and in order to compare them so that i can create temperature maps i need them to be the same angular resolution and grid size.

I have managed to Gaussian convolve each image to the same angular resolution as the worst one, however i am having trouble finding a method to re-grid each image in python and wondered if anyone knew how to go about doing this?

I wish to re-grid the images to the same grid size as the worst quality image and so i can use that as a reference image if required. Thank you

Comment: What packages are you using? What are you using to visualize? matplotlib?

Comment: I have all the basic packages installed, numpy, scipy ect and others such as astropy and APLpy. Yes i am using matplotlib

Comment: Well i have tried the imresize fuction from scipy and the resize from numpy but these dont work for my fits files, i haven't been able to find another method so far.

Comment: Why does imresize not work? Adding this information to your post, will make it useful to others. Details of what you tried, etc.

Comment: it removes too much information from the images making them unusable

Answer (score 3):

If the image headers have the correct World Coordinate System data, you can use the reproject package to resample the images:
 http://reproject.readthedocs.org/en/stable/

Comment: `reproject` is the right tool to use in most cases.  If you're dealing with cubes, at least for now FITS_tools (http://fits-tools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) has some more convenient wrappers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use FITS_tools (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/FITS_tools, it can also be installed via `$ pip install FITS_TOOLS` in the anaconda distribution of python).
Both images must have wcs in the header information.

```
import FITS_tools
to_be_projected = 'fits_file_to_be_projected.fits'
reference_fits  = 'fits_file_serving_as_reference.fits'
im1,im2 = FITS_tools.match_fits(to_be_projected,reference_fits)
```

It returns: Two images projected into the same space, and optionally the header used to project them. Once installed, you can do help(FITS_tools.match_fits) for more information.